# How to treat a folder as a DVD Video

Tags: video, dvd

I have a Video DVD and for faster access I have copied the **AUDIO_TS** and **VIDEO_TS** folders to a folder in my Hard Disk. Now, what software can I use to treat this folder as if I am watching the video on DVD. Now, there are multiple tracks, therefore simply expecting to open a single video file will not do the job.

**Edit:** I intend to make this work on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Please list your operating system.

Comment: I am using Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just download the [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) and install it. And right click on the folder you want to watch the movies from and click on option `Play with VLC media player` and it will work like you are watching DVD with enable a title button to go back on title menu.

**Edit**

The title menu button will only available if it is a DVD folder with the title menu otherwise you will able to just go on next movie in folder as in DVD.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are several programs that can play your files back as mentioned [here](http://www.magicdvdripper.com/copy-dvd-playback.htm). With Windows media player, you should be able to

> 1. Launch Windows Media Player.
> 2. Select Open from the File menu.
> 3. Choose "Any file (*.*)" from the Files of type drop-down list. And then select the VIDEO_TS.IFO file, in the VIDEO_TS folder under the folder with the same name as the movie (For example, it's "F:\temp\HOLLOWMAN\VIDEO_TS\VIDEO_TS.IFO" in the illustration above). And then click OK when you are done.